# Heroku domain registration configured to bamboo on a cedar stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, bamboo, cedar

I have a DNS config issue with Heroku while running on the Cedar Stack. It keeps thinking I'm routing my Cedar stack to Bamboo when my custom domains have the correct pointing CNAME records and are properly configured to Heroku instruction. Here's what happened:

I recently created a heroku app in the past week with a cedar stack.

```
Region: United States
Stack: Cedar
Framework: Ruby/Rails
```

And I used NameCheap to register my domain and pointed it to the CNAME record.

```
Host Name | IP Address/URL    | Record Type
@           foo.herokuapp.com   CNAME (Alias)
www         foo.herokuapp.com   CNAME (Alias)
```

I followed the [Custom Domains Heroku Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) and added the domains to my heroku app

```
$ heroku domains:add example.com
$ heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

All checks pass, but when I check on the host, it points to the deprecated Bamboo stack way of pointing to domains:

```
$ host www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.215.104
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.233.102
proxy.heroku.com has address 174.129.23.129
proxy.heroku.com has address 184.73.171.204
```

and when I visit my site on the custom domain, I receive this error in my logs

```
at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysite.com fwd="198.244.101.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

...[Heroku Error Codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h70-access-to-bamboo-http-endpoint-denied) then tells me to properly configure my custom domains according to the [Heroku Custom Domain Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#custom-subdomains), which I already did.

I've done a DNS lookup to check that my DNS records are pointing to the right CNAME and even flushed my DNS cache, but alas to no avail. Any guidance?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue. You need to go to the configuration page of zerigo and clic on configure next to the domain you have trouble. On Zerigo's site edit the CNAME record and change "proxy.heroku.com" to "yourapp.herokuapp.com". It should take a while to propagate.

You will see something like this:

```
$ host www.myapp.com
www.myapp.com is an alias for myapp.herokuapp.com.
myapp.herokuapp.com is an alias for us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com is an alias for argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 50.19.83.99
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 54.225.177.29
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 23.23.214.121
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 54.225.170.60
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 184.73.160.229
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 23.23.245.47
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 23.21.166.91
argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 184.73.213.30
```

This worked for me just now.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone finds this later, I had this issue but my mistake was pointing to "myapp.**heroku**.com" vs "myapp.**herokuapp**.com"

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow. I was just stucked in this mistake. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped somebody!