# An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, tk-toolkit

I registered my domain on heroku. On Heroku address my web-site work fine! But on my new domain address my web-site is not work. I see following mistake: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.
My heroku address: http://mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com/ - work fine
My new domain address: http://priroda-site.tk/ - is not work

**Heroku logs:**

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/appq$ heroku logs
2014-07-21T12:18:17.903687+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T12:18:17.734988+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T12:18:17.734848 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 12:18:17 +0000
2014-07-21T12:18:17.948925+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:17.734986+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-07-21T12:18:17.944099+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T12:18:17.972098+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:17.967684+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T12:18:17.938487+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 11.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:16.989193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-21T12:18:17.936717+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.7ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:17.940683+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T12:18:17.940568 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 12:18:17 +0000
2014-07-21T12:18:17.947856+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:17.965994+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T12:18:17.965891 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 12:18:17 +0000
2014-07-21T12:18:17.971296+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:18.991472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=124580f1-de0f-4be
4-8408-1759ba59f086 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=53606
2014-07-21T12:18:18.987091+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:18.986091+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
2014-07-21T12:18:18.976947+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T12:18:18.976822 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 12:18:18 +0000
2014-07-21T12:18:18.981140+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T12:18:19.335829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Peace.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=c9153d1f-bb13-42a7-9b1b-5fbcd9e43eca fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T12:18:19.336964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Bird.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=0184fbb1-3a6c-4efe-b5e1-0b8c170248e6 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T12:18:20.005790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Bird.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=00dd5ef5-2622-4a1a-9492-c6c67c2e55d2 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=454ms status=206 bytes=2672483
2014-07-21T12:18:20.074863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=34cd2190-1cf9-4a35-b715-bf153030491e fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=330ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T12:18:21.061306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Peace.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=6d8ff2e6-6d5a-4738-85f5-abbd30b16711 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1414ms status=206 bytes=27993450
2014-07-21T13:20:16.486418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-07-21T13:20:16.485660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365341+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365334+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:20:19] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365348+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365345+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365350+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365343+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365397+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/r
uby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365389+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365351+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365395+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365551+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:20:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365613+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365347+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365393+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365398+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365400+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-07-21T13:20:19.365425+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:20:19] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-07-21T13:20:20.750354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-07-21T13:20:18.877979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-21T13:27:38.008184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-07-21T13:27:38.008473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-07-21T13:27:46.655660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:27:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-07-21T13:27:46.655687+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:27:46] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-07-21T13:27:46.656072+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-07-21 13:27:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=13982
2014-07-21T13:27:47.258798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-21T13:27:48.243456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=dc8cab61-ab8e-47f9-af04-13ddc312fa43 fwd="74.202.243.44" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=166ms status=200 bytes=53646
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084392+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084400+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:13982
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084439+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T13:27:48.084288 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 74.202.243.44 at 2014-07-21 13:27:48 +0000
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084402+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084436+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-07-21T13:27:48.169488+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T13:27:48.084404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-07-21T13:27:48.239352+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 49.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T13:27:48.237623+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (45.5ms)
2014-07-21T13:27:43.647314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13982 -e production`
2014-07-21T14:02:50.797308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=11690b9a-59a6-4012-91fa-f447a22fa21c fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:02:51.035501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=c4fcb005-f091-478e-bf83-d071fc89535d fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07
-21T14:02:54.478577+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=772a8656-5ba2-4f2b-8f90-f1ffa3aefe4a fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:02:54.910759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=c32ec8e9-3c54-4d35-917a-e3b165b9ed78 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:03:06.695464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=065d5677-7914-4119-8267-ceb8cd98ba93 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:03:07.002782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=bfd55239-b2a9-42b6-82d9-a0b248ddc16c fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:05:35.184441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=8558542a-5632-41a3-8b63-6de4447f0b32 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:05:35.992088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=e05ace8e-045d-4e22-95ca-bfecf6fb388d fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:05:50.614054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=0ed8b7f4-7921-462d-bd76-14bf2cd7d777 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:05:51.420887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=0f313ebe-094b-4818-b7c6-ec3c9a2c074a fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:06:35.730002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=www.priroda-site.tk request_id=729863e1-e33f-460e-b1b0-744637d5b70e fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:06:35.978239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.priroda-site.tk request_id=8f6e7058-8242-4196-b8b1-1d32338c8a04 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:06:41.405524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=ccfde137-bdfc-4eb5-937f-16536b6efbae fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-21T14:06:41.400111+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T14:06:41.405111+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T14:06:41.396201+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T14:06:41.396087 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 14:06:41 +0000
2014-07-21T14:06:41.404399+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
2014-07-21T14:06:42.011078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Bird.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=f8c52900-db94-4fe1-b4ba-86d4955ac7c2 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T14:06:42.020591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Peace.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=a2c95155-6666-4abc-835b-e42e38900304 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T14:06:42.268714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=6cbbd898-e8ee-41eb-9d4a-cf8f9e9e9e29 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-07-21T14:06:42.851849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Bird.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=8095f19a-5199-4db9-be51-84b7ee4274e8 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=362ms status=206 bytes=2627683
2014-07-21T14:06:43.611025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Peace.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=6fdcb509-3429-4076-8515-00a0de0ca9d1 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1101ms status=206 bytes=27960556
2014-07-21T14:06:47.063494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=d2c1a195-986f-4d1d-ae02-66f3024d0d58 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:06:47.308490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=f37834b4-1cd7-4982-8c42-05cb18a47afc fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:08:22.081645+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by kotinoka2014@rambler.ru
2014-07-21T14:10:55.305823+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=ce12bb09-4fbc-499f-8598-1b37183e330a fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:10:56.051457+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=67cb9db1-2709-40f3-b391-3863aa6d1144 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:11:25.601031+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=e757fc03-75f6-455a-bddf-9251a667d756 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:11:26.600772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=fbdb8d37-e151-4f36-84e3-64fda6b7c7d4 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:12:17.222599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=42dd75d9-79b2-423d-87b2-4ed4ed760028 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:12:17.715300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H70 desc="Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=priroda-site.tk request_id=05f176c8-51cb-4632-a70c-a2785b6553b6 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-21T14:15:51.944861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=ba78436a-a3d8-4a12-8b22-102e7adcb743 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=727
2014-07-21T14:15:51.935493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-21T14:15:51.935387 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 46.63.243.55 at 2014-07-21 14:15:51 +0000
2014-07-21T14:15:51.941951+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
2014-07-21T14:15:51.938015+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2014-07-21T14:15:51.942754+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-07-21T14:15:52.926411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Bird.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=b69db571-5824-4d49-8ece-351f2a467b3e fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=311ms status=206 bytes=2597726
2014-07-21T14:15:53.773418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/videos/Peace.mp4" host=mighty-oasis-6099.herokuapp.com request_id=6271b261-bbb4-48b7-ad12-68de708c5f10 fwd="46.63.243.55" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1172ms status=206 bytes=27939166
```

**Production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: There are some problems with the configuration. You should not be on the bamboo stack, but on cedar. Did you configure CNAME correctly. You should run puma/thin or unicorn instead of webrick (webrick is for dev only)

Comment: You should not be on the bamboo stack, but on cedar. - For example. I don't understand.

Comment: `Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied` is what Rafal means

Comment: What the command I should define? (for on cedar)

Comment: It looks like this question might be a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303548/heroku-domain-registration-configured-to-bamboo-on-a-cedar-stack).